# Joomla 1.7 | First time login

Tags: authentication, joomla, registration, joomla1.7

May be you can help me:

How can I find if my user (after registration) is login first time?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you go under the User Manager from the administration backend, you can see if registered members have logged in or not.

Comment: Can you please let me know from code i need add some validations when user logged in first time after registration.

Comment: You will have to post an additional question elsewhere.  Joomla 1.7 is no longer supported and has not been for a long time, which is what this question is asking about.  I suggest updating to the latest version of Joomla and post a question about the relevant version.